# To generate barcode through web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, barcode

I want to generate barcode through my web application. I tried google to find out source code to implement it, but what I get that code was generating barcode through Windows application. But I want code to include same functionality in my web application. What should be the code for web application? What should be replacement of picturebox in web application?

Code for Windows application:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    bitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
    pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
    pictureBox1.Height = bitmap.Height;
    pictureBox1.Width = bitmap.Width;
}
```

Code to generate barcode:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string barcode = textBox1.Text;

    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(barcode.Length + 40, 150);

    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        Font ofont = new System.Drawing.Font("Free 3 of 9 Extended", 40);
        PointF point = new PointF(2f, 2f);
        SolidBrush black = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        SolidBrush white = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
        graphics.FillRectangle(white, 0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
        graphics.DrawString("*" + barcode + "*", ofont, black, point);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any c# code for this. Here is a sample html page

```
<html>
<style>
    @font-face {
        font-family: barcode;
        src: url(free3of9.ttf);
    }
</style>

<body>
    ABC
    <div style='font-family:barcode;font-size:32px;'>123456789</div>
    DEF
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SuperWebSocket](http://superwebsocket.codeplex.com/), a .net WebSocket server, to send the image data to Web client. Here is a simple example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using SuperSocket.SocketBase;
using SuperSocket.SocketBase.Config;
using SuperSocket.SocketBase.Logging;
using SuperSocket.SocketBase.Protocol;
using SuperSocket.SocketEngine;

namespace SuperSocket.QuickStart.TelnetServer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to start the server!");

            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.WriteLine();

            var appServer = new AppServer();

            //Setup the appServer
            if (!appServer.Setup(2012)) //Setup with listening port
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to setup!");
                Console.ReadKey();
                return;
            }

            appServer.NewSessionConnected += new SessionHandler<AppSession>(appServer_NewSessionConnected);

            Console.WriteLine();

            //Try to start the appServer
            if (!appServer.Start())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to start!");
                Console.ReadKey();
                return;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("The server started successfully, press key 'q' to stop it!");

            while (Console.ReadKey().KeyChar != 'q')
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                continue;
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
            //Stop the appServer
            appServer.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("The server was stopped!");
        }

        static void appServer_NewSessionConnected(AppSession session)
        {
            session.Send("Welcome to SuperSocket Telnet Server");
        }
    }
}
```

You can send image data with **session.send()**.
Then create a **div** element and draw the image in JavaScript:

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:2012/");  
ws.onmessage = function (evt) {     
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(evt.data);
    var data = "";
    var len = bytes.byteLength;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        data += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
    }
    var img = document.getElementById("image");
    img.src = "data:image/png;base64,"+window.btoa(data);   
};
```